# Read a csv file that has a JSON column in SSIS?

Tags: json, sql-server, csv, ssis, etl

I have the following CSV file that has 4 columns. The last column `addresses` holds 2 addresses history in a JSON format. I have tried to read it in SSIS but it splits the JSON along with the comma(,) instead of grouping all the addresses under one column.

I am using a flat-file connector for this. Is there any other source component for this type of content? How can I parse this in SSIS so that there are just 4 columns and the addresses appear all under one column?

```
id,title,name,addresses
J44011,Mr,James,"{""address_line_1"": 45, ""post_code"": ""XY7 10PG""},{""address_line_1"": 15, ""post_code"": ""AB7 1HG""}"
```

Comment: can you use c# nuget packages?

Comment: I suggest loading it all into a single column and parsing it inside SQL Server.

Comment: @Charles I just realised SSIS Script component cannot allow me import and retain Nuget references packages. The reference simply vanished after closing and reopening.

Comment: I'd parse the address column in a script component and load in to an address table. I provided an answer doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a script component to process the JSON into its own detail table.

I created the following dataflow:

[image]

Here are the steps to the script component:

On inputs add ID and Address columns:

[image]

On inputs and outputs: add a new output and create columns (remember to program the datatypes:

[image]

The script:

```
public class Addresses
{
    public int address_line_1 { get; set; }
    public string post_code { get; set; }
}

public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
    //Test if addresses exist, if not leave the Row processing
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Row.addresses)) return;        

    //Fix Json to make it an array of objects
    string json = string.Format("[{0}]", Row.addresses);

    //Load into an array of Addressses
    Addresses[] adds = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Addresses[]>(json);

    //Process the array
    foreach (var a in adds)
    {
        rowsAddressesBuffer.AddRow();
        rowsAddressesBuffer.ID = Row.id;
        rowsAddressesBuffer.Address1 = a.address_line_1;
        rowsAddressesBuffer.PostalCode = a.post_code;
    }
}
```

Notes:

1. The class added to store results.
2. The JSON had to be fixed to create an array of objects.
3. You need to add a reference to System.Web.Extensions.
4. This goes to the load. Make sure text qualifier is defined as a double quote (")

Comment: @ibexy it is weird how this answer is accepted since it is not related to your question!!!!!

Comment: @Yahfoufi the answer is a detailed step by step instruction that not only answers the question but goes on to implement the solution I was looking for. The missing detail here is to set the "Text Qualifier" in the flat file source component to double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried to read it in SSIS but it splits the JSON along the comma(,) instead of grouping all the addresses under one column.

In order to **force SSIS to read the flat file row in 4 columns**, you should open the flat file connection manager, go to Advanced Tab, and Add only 4 columns. Make sure the last column length is equal to 4000. This will force reading the 4th column without splitting it.

[image]

After importing data to SQL Server, you can parse the JSON content using OPENJSON() function

- [Parse and Transform JSON Data with OPENJSON (SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/convert-json-data-to-rows-and-columns-with-openjson-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: You forgot to mark the text qualifier on double quote. That's why it split into an extra column. Doing this also fixes the double double quotes inside the string.

Comment: @KeithL you're right. But it recognizes that by default. You can see that from the screenshot above since the column `TextQualified` property is set to `True`

Comment: I think the OP changed his question to fit your answer better. When I answered it was about how to handle the Json in the 4th column.

Comment: @KeithL you are right. Once I put a double quote qualifier, everything worked ok.

Comment: @KeithL this will work even without setting the text qualifier in case that JSON does not contains a row delimiter (`{CR}{LF}`)